# Where can I change the texts in the customer account?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, localisation

[image]

I'm trying to update the label for `Account Dashboard` on the image above. I found the template located at `app/design/frontend\rwd\default\template\customer/account/navigation.phtml`.

How do i edit the label?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

All of these links are added via the layout.xml. If you look at `customer.xml` in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml` and find the handle `customer_account` in the `left` reference you will see the following:

```
<block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
   <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">          
 <name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
 </block>
```

This is where the account dashboard link is added. You can change these by just declaring the link again in your theme.xml or local.xml depending on which version of magento you are using:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
  <name>account</name>
  <path>customer/account/</path>
  <label>MY AWESOME LABEL</label>
</action>
```

Comment: I get a `Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Text_List::addLink(Array` error

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the layout xml where the link is added:

```
<block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"> <name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
</block>
```

You see the text, and more important, the attribute `translate="customer"`. This means, that Magento passed the text from `<label>` to the translation method `Mage::helper('customer')->__()`, i.e. it gets translated by the `Mage_Customer` module.

You can change this translation, using you theme's `locale/en_US/translate.csv`. Create the file if it does not exist and add the following line:

```
"Mage_Customer::Account Dashboard","Your changed translation here"
```